# Windows 10 Home Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am about to upgrade my computer to Windows 10 but I am unsure about which edition to use (Home or Pro). I read on some sites that remote desktop is not included in the home edition.
A different site says that only connecting TO a computer with Win10 Home doesn't work but this computer itself can use the remote desktop client.

I need to connect via remote desktop to a server running windows server 2012. Would that be possible with the home edition of win 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, Take a look at this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/222458/should-you-upgrade-to-the-professional-edition-of-windows-10/).

> Like previous versions of Windows, Windows 10 Home offers a client for
>   connecting to Remote Desktop servers, but not the Remote Desktop
>   server itself. To host a Remote Desktop server using Windows 10’s
>   built-in Remote Desktop feature, you’ll need Windows 10 Professional.
>   However, there are many other remote-desktop solutions that don’t
>   require Windows 10 Professional and are easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is also this possibility: http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=129 wich install a Remote Desktop Server.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to connect to the server with your home edition that is quite possible.

You cannot log into your home computer from another though.  Your premise in the question is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the easiet fix, I have found, to run remote desktop on Windows Home 10:

1) Click on the search box, Cortana, or start search on the lower left of your desktop.

2) Type cmd

3) when the command prompt box opens, type mstsc

4) The remote desktop will open. Click "show options" in the bottom left corner, then click "save as" and save to your desktop.

Now you are all set to go, just like previous versions of Windows.

Comment: This appears to be an answer to something other then what the author asked.  How you run the built-in Windows RDP client wasn't part of the question